# SDL_GetKeyboardState() returns wrong scancode for all keys

Tags: c#, mono, sdl-2

I'm trying to use the SDL2-CS binding and ran into a problem with SDL_GetKeyboardState(). Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the way I access the returned array, but it seems like the data inside is wrong.

Here's a test I did:

```
SDL.SDL_PumpEvents();
states = SDL.SDL_GetKeyboardState( out arraySize );

unsafe 
{
    uint* s = (uint*)states;
    for (int i=0; i<arraySize; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] > 0 && i < 100)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

When I press 'Q', it stop at i=5 (it should be 20). With 'W' it stop at 6 instead of 26 and 'Return' stop at 10 instead of 40. I have yet to see a key that stop at the correct value. I get the same thing with .NET/mono and windows/mac. Anyone successfully used this function using the csharp bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDL_GetKeyboardState` returns an array of `Uint8`, not `uint`! As you walk through the array, each step you are seeing `sizeof(uint)` bytes and checking if an `unsigned int` value is non 0. At `i=5`, you're checking 4 scancodes, one of them being `SDLK_SCANCODE_Q`.

Check the docs: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState.

I hope your compiler warned you about this type mismatch.